# counting the elements of array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which has null elements also. I want to keep track of number of elements that have the contents in it.

```
      int counter = 0;
    for (int a = 0; i <=array1.length; a ++){
        if (array1[a] != null)
            counter ++;

    }
```

I used the above code for it. But I am getting ArrayIndexoutofBound exception at line

> if (array1[a] != null)

why is that? Can someone point it pls.

Comment: Remember that the range of an array of length n is from 0 to n-1.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a < array1.length` instead of `i <= array1.length`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
for (int a = 0; i <=array1.length; a ++){
```

by

```
for (int a = 0; i <array1.length; a++){
```

---

Your code fails on element `array1[array1.length]`, because the index must be between `0` and `array1.length - 1` inclusive.

[image]

Comment: You should explain why you did this change, otherwise the asker might make the same mistake in the future again.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is because you are iterating one time extra than the length of an array.

If the length of your array is 3. Your array stores elements like `array[0]`, `array[1]` and `array[2]`.

Index of an array or any list Map Set starts from 0.

Use `for(int a = 0; a < array1.length;a++)`

Answer (score 2):

`array1.length` is the size of the array, but since the index is 0-based, you can only go to `array1.length-1`.  So, either change your `a <= array1.length` to `a <= array1.length - 1` or change it to the more common `a < array1.length`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 for (int a = 0; i <=array1.length; a ++){
```

into

```
for (int a = 0; i <array1.length; a ++){
```

There is no element `array1[array1.length]`

If you have size of `5` array means you have index from `0` to `4`, In other word index of the first element is `0` and the index of last element is `4`

Answer (score 1):

In your "for" loop,it should be "a<=" instead of 'i'

Answer (score 1):

switch <= to < in your for loop